# Capistrano 3 SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host [hostname ]agent could not sign data with requested identity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm getting the following error while deploying my rails app to an ubuntu server, I have correctly setup ssh keys and I can ssh to the server but I'm getting the following when I try to do

```
 cap production deploy
```

This is the error message

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx: agent could not sign data with requested identity
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong since I had previously deployed and I just need to update my app to changes I have made. I have not changed my **deploy.rb, Capfile or deploy/production.rb** files since I last deployed

Comment: Try to ssh to server directly from terminal. If you can ssh then try restarting both your local machine and target server. That worked for me.

Comment: In my case, I had forgotten to change `git@example.com` to `git@github.com` in `deploy.rb`.

Comment: @scaryguy Thanks, man. In my case it was `.com` instead of `.ru`. @everyone check your server address first.

Answer (score 15):

I solved a similar issue by just issuing `ssh-add`. It seems that my current environment hasn't properly picked up the keys and readding them fixed the issue.

Comment: I had already tried that but to no avail at the time but from online research I had seen it as a recommended solution by many people

Comment: ssh-add per se did not work for me but `ssh-add ~/.ssh/path_to_key` did. I have  many keys, and the one needed appeared on the output of `ssh-add -L` already before working to no vail

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.

```
ssh-copy-id user@ipaddress
```

Helped me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but in my case I had to delete file `.ssh/known_hosts` from my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Rails from 4.1.x to 4.2, I started getting similar errors when trying to bundle. I fixed it by removing the shared bundle directory. Here's the steps I took:

1. SHH into the server
2. `cd /my/app/shared/bundle/ruby`
3. `rm -rf 2.1.0` or whatever "version" directory is there
4. Re run the deploy `cap production deploy`

You may, at this point, hit a memory snag (I did while deploying to a DigitalOcean droplet). The fix for that is to create and enable a swap file on the droplet.