# Authentication failed for user when deploying to Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am trying to run cap production deploy under my project folder using Capistrano 3. I am able to ssh into my production server using the pem as login credential. But when I run cap production deploy, I get the following message:

cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host cityspade.com: Authentication failed for user ec2-user@cityspade.com

The EC2 server has already allowed my IP for SSH connecting. No idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244400/capistrano-3-sshkitrunnerexecuteerror-exception-while-executing-on-host-ho. Or try capistrano-ssh-doctor (https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor).

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano uses your default available keys to login. You might need to set up ssh-agent and add the pem to the available keys.